# Web scraper running extremely slow

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making my first web scraper in Python. It works great but it runs extremely slow. The website loads in about 10ms but it only does like 1 every couple of seconds.  There are about 4-6 million records I need to scrape through.  Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import json
import re
import urllib
import threading

prox = {"http" : "127.0.0.1:8888", "https" : "127.0.0.1:8888"}


def GetVS(Soup):
    return Soup.find('input', {'name' : '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']

def GetEV(Soup):
    return Soup.find('input', {'name' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

def GetSearch(Viewstate, Eventvalidation):
    return requests.post('website', 
        data="__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24rblSearchType%241&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE="+urllib.quote(Viewstate, '')+"&__EVENTVALIDATION="+urllib.quote(Eventvalidation, '')+"&ctl00%24txtsearch=&ctl00%24rdoSearch=rdoSite&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24rblSearchType=PropertyID&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24txtOwner=",
        verify=False,
        headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36", "Referer" : "https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/", "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

def PropertySearch(PropertyID, Viewstate, Eventvalidation):
    return requests.post('website', 
        data="__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE="+urllib.quote(Viewstate, '')+"&__EVENTVALIDATION="+urllib.quote(Eventvalidation, '')+"&ctl00%24txtsearch=&ctl00%24rdoSearch=rdoSite&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24rblSearchType=PropertyID&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24txtPropertyID="+urllib.quote(PropertyID, '')+"&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24btnSearch=Click+Here+to+Search+for+Property", 
        verify=False,
        headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36", "Referer" : "https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/", "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

def getAmmount(Selid, PropertyID, Viewstate, Eventvalidation):
    return requests.post('website', 
        data="__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24grdResults&__EVENTARGUMENT=Select%24"+urllib.quote(Selid, '')+"&__VIEWSTATE="+urllib.quote(Viewstate, '')+"&__EVENTVALIDATION="+urllib.quote(Eventvalidation, '')+"&ctl00%24txtsearch=&ctl00%24rdoSearch=rdoSite&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24rblSearchType=PropertyID&ctl00%24cpMain%24ctl01%24txtPropertyID="+urllib.quote(PropertyID, ''), 
        verify=False,
        headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36", "Referer" : "https://nevadatreasurer.gov/UPSearch/", "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

def GetData(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblAmountValue"}).text

def GetPropertyID(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblPropertyIDValue"}).text

def GetReportYear(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblReportYearValue"}).text

def GetName(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblNameValue"}).text

def GetAddress1(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblAddress1Value"}).text

def GetAddress2(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblAddress2Value"}).text

def GetCity(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblCityValue"}).text

def GetState(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblStateValue"}).text

def GetZip(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblZipValue"}).text

def GetInst(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblInstitutionValue"}).text

def GetDesc(Html):
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html)
    return Soup.find('span', {"id" : "cpMain_ctl01_lblDescriptionValue"}).text

Request_1           = requests.get('website', verify=False)
Soup_1              = BeautifulSoup(Request_1.text)
Viewstate_1             = GetVS(Soup_1)
Eventvalidation_1       = GetEV(Soup_1)

    Request_2           = GetSearch(Viewstate_1, Eventvalidation_1)
    Soup_2              = BeautifulSoup(Request_2.text)
    Viewstate_2             = GetVS(Soup_2)
    Eventvalidation_2       = GetEV(Soup_2)

    def dowork(start):
        while start < 4000000:      
            start = start + 1
            Request             = PropertySearch(str(start), Viewstate_2, Eventvalidation_2)
            Soup                = BeautifulSoup(Request.text)
            Viewstate           = GetVS(Soup)
            Eventvalidation     = GetEV(Soup)

            regex = re.compile("Over \$100.*__doPostBack.*Select\$(.*)\&")
            r = regex.findall(Request.text)

            for i in r:
                print GetData(getAmmount(i, str(start), Viewstate, Eventvalidation).text)

    threads = []
    for i in range(50):
        t = threading.Thread(target=dowork, args=(i*100000+1000000,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of strange things about this piece of code:

> ```
> def dowork(start):
>     while start < 4000000:      
>         start = start + 1
>         # ...
>
>         regex = re.compile("Over \$100.*__doPostBack.*Select\$(.*)\&")
>         r = regex.findall(Request.text)
>
>         for i in r:
>             # ...
>
> threads = []
> for i in range(50):
>     t = threading.Thread(target=dowork, args=(i*100000+1000000,))
> ```

First of all, you don't need to compile the regex in every iteration, and not even in every thread. It seems this can be a global constant, compiled only once.

The threads run `dowork` with a different `start` parameter: 1m, 1.1m, 1.2m, ..., 5.8m, 5.9m. The smaller problem is that `dowork` only runs until 4m, so threads 30~49 will do nothing. The *big* problem is that they *all* run until 4m. I think you really meant this instead:

> ```
> def dowork(start0, maxcnt):
>     counter = 0
>     while counter < maxcnt:      
>         counter += 1
>         start = str(start0 + counter)
>         # ...
> ```

This has some other improvements as well:

- `counter += 1` simpler than `counter = counter + 1`
- Convert `start` to string once, reuse multiple times within the function
- `maxcnt` is a parameter instead of hardcoded 10**5, because the caller controls the `start0` parameter, and the two are closely related

#### Coding style

Please follow [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python coding style guide. Especially, `snake_case` is preferred for method names, instead of `CamelCase`.